# How do I manage authorization (not authentication) with node and a postgresql db?

Tags: node.js, postgresql

This question is regarding authorization, not authentication which i will be managing with passportjs. How do i restrict access for data that's bound to specific users without spreading `user_id`'s all over every table in the database?

Should i create a new database user for each new user of my app and restrict access that way? Or is the "user id in every table" approach actually a good way to go?

I'm working on a project right now where someone else wrote the authorization logic and it works using a kind of `authorization path` in the code so it can find which user a resource belongs to using some breadcrumb logic.

But I'm really at a loss here and I'm having a hard time finding any information regarding this since almost all articles that I find are about authentication rather than authorization. And I do not mean access to a resource, but rather the filtration of data returned from a resource that the user has access to.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to restrict access of users to certain objects, you either have to store that information with the user or with the object.

The latter is the preferred way because it makes permissions disappear with the object. That's the way PostgreSQL does it – it stores an *access control list* (ACL) with every object.

So you can either use PostgreSQL to implement privileges (then every application user or at least every group with equal privileges has to have a database user, and you can use permissions on tables and columns and *row level security*), or you implement it in your application and have some sort of ACL with every row in the database.